# How to set bitmap size that fill parent?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I want to creat a bit map in the size that fill parent of the app window. how can i do that?

```
Bitmap maskImage =  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img);

ImageView on = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.on);
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(maskImage.getWidth(), maskImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
on.setImageBitmap(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Only a single additional line is needed:

Once you have your `ImageView`:

```
ImageView on = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.on);
on.setImageBitmap( . . . );
on.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

`ScaleType`s are options for scaling the bounds of your image. You can read more about `ScaleType`s in the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

Comment: but it dosent work and dident fit the the sreen. when I idd this pic from drawble it fits the screen. but when I add given bitmap it dosent fit.